# Наблюдение о родстве слов

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Наверное, я сейчас скажу глупость, но вдруг подумалось: если "гора" и "горе" - всего лишь похожие слова, то почему так же похожи "круча" и "кручина"? По смыслу эти обе пары тоже ведь похожи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Круча и кручина тоже омонимы.Круча- от "крутой" - крутой спуск, а кручина (по Крылову) восходит к той же основе, что и польское krecz, имеющее значение "головокружение, судороги". Тот же корень, но с иной гласной находим в диалектном крячить – "тащить тяжелую ношу".
[КРУЧИНА](http://www.slovopedia.com/25/202/1650354.html)

Ст.-слав. кроучина χολέρα, наглокроучиньство "вспыльчивость",укр. кручина́ "печаль",  словен. ukrokniti "изгибаться, извиваться", ukročiti "согнуть", чеш. kručinkа "дрок" (бот.), польск. kręcz "головокружение, судороги, столбняк", kręczek "головокружение".
Наличие -č- в зап.-слав. и цслав. свидетельствует в пользу исходной формы *krǫk-; ( См. также кря́кать.) Во всяком случае, не от круто́й. 
[КРУЧИНА](http://vasmer.slovaronline.com/%D0%9A/%D0%9A%D0%A0/6206-KRUCHINA)

Comment: Кручина - голово**кружение** - скрючить - крутить. Зачем отрицать очевидные связи, не могу понять.

Comment: Эти-то связаны. А "круча"здесь при чём?

Comment: Вы сами написали, что круча - от крутой...

Крутой - противоположность прямому, ровному, спокойному и тд. Кручей называли водоворот в реке, а на горную кручу нет прямой тропы, как правило. Спиральные дороги в горах устраивают. Приходится крутиться вокруг крутых горок. Я уже отвечал, но местный сумасшедший князек минусует мои ответы по десятку в день. Он вполне может переделать мой коммент в ответ, поставить минус, потом опять в коммент. Мне пришлось удалить почти все свои ответы, а оставшиеся сделать общими. Но дурачок что-нибудь придумает)))

Comment: Только крутой-не от "крутить"(крутить= кружить - от"круг"), крутой-резко обрывающийся, отвесный(от праслав. формы *krǫt-: *kręt-)

Comment: Посмотрите у Преображенского статью "крутъ". Он приводит однокоренные *круть, круча, кручь, крутизна; крутильня, вкрутую; окрутить... и еще сто других! Формы, которые Вы приводите, ничего доказать не могут, все это сплошной туман. Крутой - не от крутить??? Фантастика и фило/логический самообман, мягко говоря.

Answer (score -1):

Кр--   исходный смысл  жечь калить ( карать курить крутить черный укорачивать соединять)
Гр--   поднимать ( гряда гора ). Горе от корня гореть (  у кого дом или стог сгорел) . Кручина (печаль) имеет корень скорее греч. от НК ( НаКлонять поНиКнуть давить склонить победить ( НиКе НиКолай ) получается двукоренное слово - КР-НК.